# Register class itself to factory

Tags: c++, factory

I have a question about the factory pattern. I programmed a factory, that has a static function called registerIt. It accepts a string for the class name and a pointer to the creator function of any class.

```
static void CharacterFactory::registerit(const std::string& classname, Creator creator)
{
   table[classname] = creator;
}
```

The table is

```
std::map<std::string, CharacterFactory::Creator> CharacterFactory::table;
```

Creator

```
typedef std::auto_ptr<Actor> Type;
typedef Type (*Creator)();
```

Actor is the Base class

The classes itself have function for registering. For example the class "Player"

```
static void registerToFactory(){
    CharacterFactory::registerit("Player",&create);
    std::cout<<"player created"<<std::endl;     
    }
```

My Problem is, how can I tell the classes to register itself to the static factory? Everything works, if I call registerToFactory in the main class. But I want to do it more dynamically, so I only have to change code in new classes and not everywhere in my code.

The whole code below:

Factory.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Actor.h"
#include <string>
#include<map>
namespace Character{
class Actor;
class CharacterFactory
{

public:
typedef std::auto_ptr<Actor> Type;
typedef Type (*Creator)();

CharacterFactory(void);
~CharacterFactory(void);

Type create(const std::string& classname);
static void registerit(const std::string& classname, Creator creator);

private:
static std::map<std::string, Creator> table;
};
}
```

Actor:

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
#include"CharacterFactory.h"
#include<iostream>
namespace Character{

class Actor
{
public:

static Actor* create(){std::cout<<"dummy"<<std::endl;return NULL;};
static Actor* create(int dmg){std::cout<<"dummy"<<std::endl;return NULL;};

Actor(void):damage(0),healthPoints(0),lastUpdate(0){};
Actor(int dmg):damage(dmg){};
~Actor(void);

virtual void update(void)=0;
virtual void update(int deltaMillis)=0;

protected:

int lastUpdate;


//Attribute
int healthPoints;
int damage;
//Amor amor;
//Weapon weapon;
//Ai ai;


//Networking

};

}
```

Player:

```
#pragma once
#include "Actor.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "CharacterFactory.h"

namespace Character{
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
class Player:public Actor
{
public:

void update(void){};
void update(int deltaMillis){};


static std::auto_ptr<Actor> create(){
    return std::auto_ptr<Actor>(new Player);
}
Player(void);

~Player(void);
static void registerToFactory(){
        CharacterFactory::registerit("Player",&create);
        std::cout<<"player created"<<std::endl;     
    }
inline int getDamage(void){ return damage;};
};
#endif
}
```

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: You can do it in a constructor of a static object (of a new class you must write). Then you don't have to touch your main function each time a new class is added. You still need to define these static objects somewhere, one for each class.

Comment: if I insert `static Player player` after all code in player.h i get an error in xtree? Can you give me some example please? i would like to create the static object in its class or somewhere in the .cpp file

Comment: I have tried a workaround. There's a function `loadCharacters()`. It creates static objects of every Character, so the constructor is called. Then I created an instance of the factory. In its constructor the function is called. so I only have to change the static instances in the function. But I have an factory object, which I don't need.

Comment: Let me try again. *You can do it in a constructor of a static object (**of a new class you must write**).* Not static objects of the Player class. And you never add object definitions to an .h file.

Comment: To make it a bit more explicit: this new class, name it `RegistryRunner`, should accept a string and a function as its constructor arguments. Then it registers them in the factory. This way, when a new class is added, a new `RegistryRunner` static object is added along with it. Existing code should not be touched.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the constructor or dynamic initialisation expression for a static variable, and the compiler will ensure that runs before calling `main()`.